# Android Studio – Which .java file is executed when I run tests?

Tags: java, android, testing, intellij-idea

Where can I choose which `.java` to execute when running an Android Studio **test**?

I have 3 `.java` files and only one is being executed.

When searching the project for references for the specific `.java` which runs every time, I've only found the file name in `workspace.xml` file which is probably irrelevant.

Comment: If I undertand correctly, what you want is to configure a run configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer:

right click on a specific test class -> RUN -> [test run option]

Answer (score 1):

To add on mos182's answer.

The first .java (or more to the point in android first Activity to be launched) is indeed indicated in the app manifest, it is the activity set with the intent filter:

Just to clarify. A manifest is one per application regardless of how many packages your app has.

I hope this helps make sense of things

Answer (score 0):

You should check your AndroidManifest.xml file. Here you define which class to run first when you launch your app.

Look out for this line of code

```
android:name=".<your class name>"
```

So if your class is called MainActivity.java, it will should look like the following

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: there can't be a manifest file for tests.. the tests aren't a part of the apk